# Show scrollbar in webpage like desktop in android phone

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, scrollbar

I have designed a responsive webpage using HTML5. I used the following code to display some content with scroll bar.

```
div {height:300px; overflow: auto;}
```

If I view the webpage in desktop the scroll bar displays. If I view the webpage in android phone, I can scroll the section but couldn't view the scroll bar like desktop.

Is there any way to display scroll bar?